# How show registers per hour - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm working in MySql, I need to get a MySQL query with all the records in a table grouped by hour, but I also need the times when there are no records.

For example, I have a users table, I want to get registered users by the hour and to give me something like this:

---

1:00 10 
2:00 15 
3:00 3 
4:00 0 
 
5:00 0 
6:00 1 
. 
. 
. 
24:00 12

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `hours` table and add 24 records into it, one for each hour.

Once done, you can `LEFT JOIN` that, with `users` table and use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` by applying `HOUR` function to extract the hour from date (assuming the column in question is a datetime column), e.g.

```
SELECT h.hour, COUNT(u.*)
FROM hours h LEFT JOIN users u ON h.hour = HOUR(u.registered)
GROUP BY h.hour;
```